# Replacing items in a list with predetermined values

Tags: python-2.7

Let's say I'm making a tile map out of a Python 2.7 list, and it looks something like this...:

```
tilemap = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
    [2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

...and I assign variables like this...:

```
grass = 0
dirt = 1
water = 2
```

How can I print this list so that it displays the variables as strings to give a more complete look to the map?

Answer (score 0):

If you instead could store the names in an array, you can make it very simple with a list comprehension;

```
> tiletype = ['grass', 'dirt', 'water']

> [[tiletype[x] for x in y] for y in tilemap]

[['grass', 'grass', 'grass', 'grass', 'grass'], 
 ['dirt',  'dirt',  'dirt',  'grass', 'grass'], 
 ['water', 'water', 'water', 'dirt',  'grass'], 
 ['water', 'water', 'dirt',  'grass', 'grass'], 
 ['water', 'dirt',  'grass', 'grass', 'grass']]
```